# Can't understand why my args doesn't work in discord.js

Tags: arguments, discord.js

Well, so I was trying to make code that won't send embed if args isn't defined

```
var member = message.mentions.members.first();

If(args[0] == member) {
//Here's my embed
} else {
channel.message.send('you need to mention someone to do it');
}
```

I was trying to find answers why it won't work but couldn't found anything about. Also I was trying to replace `if(args[0] == member)` with `if(args[1] == member)` or `if(args[0] == message.mention.members.first())` but it didn't help. I'm new in JavaScript and don't know a lot about it so please help me.

Comment: what is `args[0]`? is it the member's ID? Also, what is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I think I know what your doing, This will work.

```
var member = message.mentions.users.first(); //Gets the pinged user.
if(!member) return message.reply("There is no user defined in this message.")//checks if a member is pinged.
//rest of code
```

`member` doesn't need to be set as a argument, This will work the same way.
I am using discord.js version 11.5.1, Hopefully this will still work for you.